# Save model in Yii twice - getting "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry"

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to save newly created yii model twice - first to get auto-incremented id. And the second time to save that id-related stuff:

```
$node = new Node;
$node->attributes = $attrs;
$node->save(); // now I have 'id'

$node->vector = calcVector($node->id); // vector is based on 'id'
$node->save();
```

The <s>second save</s> (**edit: error was thrown elsewhere**) throws this error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry`. The expected behavior is to simply update the already saved model.

**What is the right way to save it second time?**

(I could do `$node = Node::model()->findByPk($node->id);`, but that doesn't seem right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, so apparently the problem was not in what I describe above.

**Saving twice is working as expected - 1st call inserts, 2nd call updates.**

The problem was probably that I was saving the model in `beforeSave()`. I've had a complicated and confusing logic in there, didn't realize what's happening..

Comment: That's why you should avoid complicated and confusing logics in the first place ;). If you call `save()` from `beforeSave()` then you end up in an endless loop, because `save()` will trigger another `beforeSave()`.

Comment: I was trying to achieve sophistication, by adding stuff to beforeSave - which might get triggered in many cases. However, I now think that it's better to repeat myself, rather than making the code too clever. Sometimes it's hard to find the right balance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

just set

```
$node->isNewRecord = false;
```

then

```
$node->save();
```

cheers

Comment: I don't think it's necessary in the situation I describe above. (although it might prove helpful for people in similar situation)

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar situation where I needed to save a model to database multiple times. I accomplished it by simply instantiating a model after saving it:

```
foreach ($partsIdArray as $id)
    {
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); // loading form values
        $model->part_id = $id;
        $model->save();
        $model = new \backend\models\Abc();
    }
```